# Get result in input tag from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, input

I want the value from jquery into input type tag.
Here is my input tag:

```
<input readonly type="number" class="showResult" name="showTDEE0" id="showTDEE0">
```

And my jquery code is:

```
var fact1 = Math.round(TDEE * 1.399);
var as = fact1.toString()+"df";
$("#showTDEE0").val(as);
```

With out concatenating "df" i manage to make it value of input but with concatenation "df" it doesnt work

Comment: what is TDEE??? Anyway, it should work

Comment: Well your input type is number and by using `toString()` and string concatenation you are trying to input a string. change type to `type="text"`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mLa2qg5q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are setting the `type` attribute to `number`, and you are trying to set a value for your input that contains non-numeric characters (`df`).
The following code worked fine for me in jquery 1.11.0:

```js
$("#showTDEE0").val( Math.round(TDEE * 1.399) + "df" );
alert($("#showTDEE0").val());
```

### JSFiddle

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/7j7mLert/) for reference.

Comment: Good to know! Please don't forget to mark at least one of the provided answers as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number input, so the browser refuses to set the value to anything that is not a number.

Try this:

`<input readonly type="text" class="showResult" name="showTDEE0" id="showTDEE0">`

Answer (score 0):

Your input type is `number` the value you are trying to give it is a `string`.

You will need to change the type of the input if you want to give it a string value.

i.e. `type="text"`